# Proving that (0,1) is closed under a given function

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Let G be the interval $(0,1)$ and let * : $G^2$ $\to$ $G$ be defined by 
$x$*$y$ = $\frac{xy}{1-x-y+2xy}$ .
Show that this is a group.**

I am attempting to verify that this satisfies the closure condition.

Let $x, y \in (0,1)$. So far, I have noticed that since $x, y \in (0,1)$, $xy \in (0,1)$. Also, $xy < min(x,y)$, and so $2xy < x+y$.

Since $xy$ is positive, if I can show that $1-x-y+2xy > xy$, then $x*y \in (0,1)$, as needed. Could you please give me some hints in obtaining that inequality?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $ 2xy - x - y + 1 > xy\iff  xy - x - y + 1 > 0$. But this is equivalent to $$x(y-1) - (y-1) = (x-1)(y-1) > 0$$

Answer (score 2):

The inequality you seek is equivalent to $1-x-y+xy>0,$ which is $(1-x)(1-y)>0.$
And since $x,y \in (0,1)$ you have as needed each of $1-x,\ 1-y$ positive.

Comment: The operation is to map the two numbers to the positive reals with the Moebius transformation $t/(1-t),$ multiply, then map back with the inverse transformation $t/(1+t).$ Which is why it does come out associative.

Answer (score 0):

We have,

$$1-x-y+2xy > xy$$

$$\iff 1-x-y+xy > 0$$

$$\iff 1(1-x)-y(1-x) > 0$$

$$\iff (1-y)(1-x) > 0$$

Comment: Your inequalities should be strict, surely?

Comment: Thanks for correcting @ZainPatel